# Regex find comma not inside quotes

Tags: regex

I'm checking line by line in C#

Example data:

```
bob jones,123,55.6,,,"Hello , World",,0
jim neighbor,432,66.5,,,Andy "Blank,,1
john smith,555,77.4,,,Some value,,2
```

[Regex to pick commas outside of quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632475/regex-to-pick-commas-outside-of-quotes) doesn't resolve second line, it's the closest.

Comment: If you are using C#, then why bother with a regex? Much easier to just use a basic loop.

Comment: thanks JDB, I need a regex

Comment: Don't use regex. You need a CSV parser.

Comment: with all due respect what is so difficult about understanding a simple constraint without having to explain it. I get the "use csv parser" Not an option, please tell me you have never encountered similar

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try the following regex:

`(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)`

---

Here is a demonstration:

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/xB7rQ7/1)

---

- It does not match the second line because the `"` you inserted does not have a closing quotation mark.
- It will not match values like so: `,r"a string",10` because the letter on the edge of the `"` will create a word boundary, rather than a non-word boundary.

---

### Alternative version

`(".*?,.*?"|.*?(?:,|$))`

This will match the content and the commas and is compatible with values that are full of punctuation marks

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/rY2gB7/1)

Comment: not working with line punctuations ie question marks, periods

Comment: Where are those punctuations located in the string as an example?

Comment: I've put in an alternative version, hopefully that works with your code... if not, we shall come up with something else.

Comment: To compile correctly in C# use double double quotes for escaping instead of a slash double quote. ex: "" instead of \"

Comment: This may help with finding the opposite - [removing commas inside quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23205667/845584)

Comment: The alternative version does not work with CSV files, where the quotes are optional. The original looks better but fails identifying the first comma in this example: _"bob jones","","123",55.6,,,"Hello , World",,0_. Unfortunately I'm not proficient enough to offer a solution :-)

Comment: You can also use similar regex to find other strings not in quotes (?!\B"[^"]*)SOMEOTHERSTRING(?![^"]*"\B)

Comment: Found a better working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25544437/3459910)

Comment: There's might be more thorough solution but this solution saved my code interview, thanks!

Comment: Brilliant ! found this answer through https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/351

Answer (score 2):

The below regex is for parsing each fields in a line, *not* an entire line

Apply the methodical and desperate regex technique: Divide and conquer

#### Case: field does not contain a quote

- abc,
- abc(end of line)

`[^,"]*(,|$)`

#### Case: field contains exactly two quotes

- abc"abc,"abc,
- abc"abc,"abc(end of line)

`[^,"]*"[^"]*"[^,"]*(,|$)`

#### Case: field contains exactly one quote

- abc"abc(end of line)
- abc"abc, (and that there's no quote before the end of this line)

`[^,"]*"[^,"]$`

`[^,"]*"[^"],(?!.*")`

Now that we have all the cases, we then '|' everything together and enjoy the resultant monstrosity.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer written by Vasili Syrakis does not work with negative numbers inside quotation marks such as:

```
bob jones,123,"-55.6",,,"Hello , World",,0
jim neighbor,432,66.5
```

Following  regex works for this purpose:

```
,(?!(?=[^"]*"[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$))
```

But I was not successful with this part of input:

```
,Andy "Blank,
```

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern `".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hA6fB1)

Comment: `(*SKIP)` an `(*FAIL)` are not valid in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

print re.sub(',(?=[^"]*"[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)',"",string)
```