# Remove more than one comma in between quotes in CSV file using Regex

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

all! Have CSV files coming in with with text inside double quotes that contain one or more commas and I am wondering if there is a regex form for Notepad++ that would remove any number of commas inside a CSV file.

For example I need to go from the this:

```
text,text1,"interesting, text,"
```

To this:

```
text,text1,"interesting text"
```

There can be 1,2 or more commas inside the quotes.

Anyone know a of a way to make this happen using regex form in Notepad++?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd better use a csv parser, it exists for many languages.

Answer (score 6):

use this pattern

```
,(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

and replace with nothing
it is looking for a comma `,` that does not see an optional even number of double quotes `"` to the end of the string