# replace all commas in quotes with regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to replace all commas in a string that between quotes in notepad++.

I almost got there with [regex to remove comma between double quotes notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205606/regex-to-remove-comma-between-double-quotes-notepad), but not quite.  As it stands it is only replacing the first comma.

To summarize this post it uses Find What: `("[^",]+),([^"]+")` Replace: `\1\2`  (which I changed to `\1~\2` )

Is there a way in regex to catch all instances of the comma between the quotes?

edit: Add a few representative strings:

```
1,G 32,170696,01/06/2015,Jun-17,"M12 X 1,50 - 4H GO SRG",P U7,,,,SRG ,"G 32_170696_06-2017_M12 X 1,50 - 4H GO SRG_P U7.pdf"
3,13247,163090,01/11/2015,Nov-17,"PG 0,251 to 0,500 inch",P U7,,,,,"13247_163090_11-2017_PPG 0,251 to 0,500 inch_P U7.pdf"
9,PI 1496,182411,01/04/2015,Apr-17,"6,000 - 6,018mm GO-NOGO  PPG",,,,,PPG,"PI 1496_182411_04-2017_6,000 - 6,018mm GO-NOGO  PPG.pdf"
```

Comment: You just need to click *Replace all* several times until no matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: if you do that you will also replace commas outside quotes.

Comment: You should add a representative sample string to your question. Also try to format your question better, see: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one pass using this pattern:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|([^"]*(?:"[^,"]*"[^"]*)*"))[^",]*\K,([^",]*+(?:"(?1)|$))?
```

with this replacement: `~\2`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/LEL7mU/1)

details:

```
(?:
    \G(?!^) # contiguous to a previous match
  | # OR
    ([^"]*(?:"[^,"]*"[^"]*)*") # capture group 1: first match
                               # reach the first quoted part with commas
)
[^",]* \K ,  #"#
( # capture group 2: succeeds after the last comma
    [^",]*+  #"#
    (?:
        " (?1) #"# reach the next quoted part with commas
               # (using the capture group 1 subpattern)
      | # OR
        $ # end of the string: (this set a default behavior: when
          # the closing quote is missing)
    )
)?
```

Comment: Wow, nice bit of regex. It seems to strip out commas after the last " though. At least for me. I struggled to follow it a little so haven't managed to fix it myself. I tested on this data:

123|"Test, Test, Test",456,789,"One, Two"<NEWLINE>
246|"Test, Test, Test",456,789,One<NEWLINE>