# Split a string with characters %" in groovy

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy

For example,we have a String name test as given below

```
def test = "HAVING first_name like "%Hello,Ram%" AND last_name like "%XYZ%",order by id asc,name desc"
```

So,after splitting i would like to have a result like

```
test1 = HAVING first_name like "%Hello,Ram%" AND last_name like "%XYZ%"

test2 = order by id asc,name desc
```

How to split such strings in grooyy? I tried splitting it by checking `contains(",")` and using the `split` function, but it would also split `"%Hello,Ram%"` which is not the result required

```
def a = 'HAVING first_name like "%Hello,Ram%" AND last_name like "%XYZ%",order by id asc,name desc'

def v = a.contains(",")

if(v){
 a.split(",")
 println a
}​​​
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Comment: @cfrick I have updated the code block in my above question. If i didnot had "%Hello,Ram%" on my string i could have used the output of the above program and manipulated the output.But i cant do it as such in this case.

Comment: Split does not mutate `a` but returns an array with the result.  if you dont assign the result, this is a no-op.

Comment: @cfrick so is there any way of returning an array like `[HAVING first_name like "%Hello,Ram%" AND last_name like "%XYZ%",order by id asc,name desc]`.If we are able to split it as such in the array we can do the other part.Like maybe if can get my desired result from array[1] as order by id asc,name desc .Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: The result of `split` is this

Comment: Are you asking how to split on commas that are not inside % delimiters?  Though if you are I'm not sure why you're not including a split on asc,name in your desired output.

Comment: @Daniel yeah i wanted to split on commas that are not inside % delimiters.Yeah i could have used on asc,name but this values are dynamic values.It can be anything but the structure of the string would be as i mentioned in the question.So,is there any way i can split from %" these characters.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like what you really want to do is find commas that are not inside %xxx% delimiters and split on them.  This is effectively a duplicate of [Regex find comma not inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105360/regex-find-comma-not-inside-quotes/21106122) which has more info on how the regex works.

```
def r = "(?!\\B%[^%]*),(?![^%]*%\\B)"
def test = """HAVING first_name like "%Hello,Ram%" AND last_name like "%XYZ%",order by id asc,name desc"""

def result = test.split(r)
```

In this, your `result` will be an array of strings (I'm not quoting them here, for clarity):

```
[
  HAVING first_name like "%Hello,Ram%" AND last_name like "%XYZ%"
  order by id asc
  name desc
]
```

The point I was trying to make in my comment is that the comma between asc and name is not inside percent signs, and therefor will be split on as well.