# How to replace comma with pipe?

Tags: powershell

I am in the situation where I need to replace the comma with pipe using PowerShell. the fields are within double quotes so I need to remove them as well. but Some fields have comma in the data so When I replace, I should keep fields commas with while space.

Data look like this:

```
"Whaling, Mark","faflitto@cgf.com"
```

I want data to be like this:

```
Whaling Mark |faflitto@cgf.com
```

How to achieve this using PowerShell?. Help appreciated.

My script is this for now:

```
(Get-Content -ReadCount 0 Compliance2022.txt) -replace ',','|' -replace '"',' ' | Set-Content COMPLIANCE2022_.txt
```

Comment: Honestly, `Import-Csv pathtofile.ext | Export-Csv pathtofile2.ext -Delimiter '|'`

Comment: I appreciate your help. it is not working my case. i guess because it is txt file even though it is comma separated..  Thank you anyway @SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: In which sense is not working?

Comment: I ran this code Get-Process Import-Csv pathtofile.ext | Export-Csv pathtofile2.ext -Delimiter '|' . it was throwing errors. i knew i made some mistake. trying ...

Comment: Why is `Get-Process` before `Import-Csv` ? That might be your issue. Furthermore, you should clarify [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71945645/edit) instead of in comments.

Comment: I am so sorry. it is working but there are double quotes in the fields and some fields have comma those should be removed and replace with white space.  Thank you very much. @SantiagoSquarzon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did **NOT** test this whole line, just the code between the Get-Content and Set-Content commands.  The regex came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21106122/4190564).

```
(Get-Content -ReadCount 0 Compliance2022.txt) | ForEach-Object {($_ -Split '(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)') -Join(' | ')} | Set-Content COMPLIANCE2022_.txt
```

Odds are it misses exactly what you want, but maybe we can fine tune it to get to work.

**EDIT:**

This version removes the quotes.

```
(Get-Content -ReadCount 0 Compliance2022.txt) | ForEach-Object {(($_ -Split '(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)') -Join(' | ')) -replace '"', " "} | Set-Content COMPLIANCE2022_.txt
```