# Pyspark String to Array Conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I am trying to convert the data in the column from string to array format for data flattening. I am using the below code to achieve it.

```
`def to_array(multi_select_cols, df, delimiter):
    for col in multi_select_cols:
        df = df.withColumn("col_name_array", F.split(df[col], delimiter))
        df = df.drop(col).withColumnRenamed("col_name_array", col)
    return df`
```

Whenever there is a name field or comma being used as a value separator rather than a delimiter the above code does not support.

For example, in the below table data to_array function will convert the reference_id column data to array as expected when the delimiter is comma (,). But for the reporter's column first and last names are split into two array elements.
[image: sample data]

Rather than specifying a different delimiter for reporters' column is there a better way of doing the conversion.

[image: Sample Input and Output]

Comment: Please provide BOTH example input and output.

Comment: updated the sample Input and output

Comment: Please check my updated answer. It correct splits on both the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I adopted this answer to solve your problem. Basically, F.split function can take a regular expression pattern. So your splitting criteria can be as complex as you want. You are not limited to only simple delimiters. Here's the full code below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21106122/3238085

Try the following regex on which to split. This regex matches with all comma which are unquoted. If a comma is within matching single quotes, it is rejected:

`(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)`

Code :

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession



spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parser.escapedStringLiterals", True)


data1 = [

["1001","'John , F','Kenneth , C'","20113,20345,30456"],
["1002","'Vista , R','Lee , J'","40231,30690"],
["1003","'Luci , L','Rex , Y'","10067"],
["1004","'Matt , C'","60912,90367,80542"],

      ]

df1Columns = ["id","reporters","reference_id"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)

print("Given Dataframe")
df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)

df1_reference_split = df1.withColumn("reference_array_col",  F.split("reference_id", "(?!\B'[^']*),(?![^']*'\B)") ).withColumn("reference_size", F.size("reference_array_col"))
print("Reference Split Dataframe")
df1_reference_split.show(n=100, truncate=False)



df1_reporters_split = df1_reference_split.withColumn("reporters_array_col", F.split("reporters", "(?!\B'[^']*),(?![^']*'\B)") ).withColumn("reporter_size", F.size("reporters_array_col"))
print("Reporters Split Dataframe")
df1_reporters_split.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
Given Dataframe
+----+------------------------+-----------------+
|id  |reporters               |reference_id     |
+----+------------------------+-----------------+
|1001|'John , F','Kenneth , C'|20113,20345,30456|
|1002|'Vista , R','Lee , J'   |40231,30690      |
|1003|'Luci , L','Rex , Y'    |10067            |
|1004|'Matt , C'              |60912,90367,80542|
+----+------------------------+-----------------+

Reference Split Dataframe
+----+------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+
|id  |reporters               |reference_id     |reference_array_col  |reference_size|
+----+------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+
|1001|'John , F','Kenneth , C'|20113,20345,30456|[20113, 20345, 30456]|3             |
|1002|'Vista , R','Lee , J'   |40231,30690      |[40231, 30690]       |2             |
|1003|'Luci , L','Rex , Y'    |10067            |[10067]              |1             |
|1004|'Matt , C'              |60912,90367,80542|[60912, 90367, 80542]|3             |
+----+------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+

Reporters Split Dataframe
+----+------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-------------+
|id  |reporters               |reference_id     |reference_array_col  |reference_size|reporters_array_col        |reporter_size|
+----+------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-------------+
|1001|'John , F','Kenneth , C'|20113,20345,30456|[20113, 20345, 30456]|3             |['John , F', 'Kenneth , C']|2            |
|1002|'Vista , R','Lee , J'   |40231,30690      |[40231, 30690]       |2             |['Vista , R', 'Lee , J']   |2            |
|1003|'Luci , L','Rex , Y'    |10067            |[10067]              |1             |['Luci , L', 'Rex , Y']    |2            |
|1004|'Matt , C'              |60912,90367,80542|[60912, 90367, 80542]|3             |['Matt , C']               |1            |
+----+------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-------------+
```