# How to refactor a regex that's getting flagged by SonarLint as 'can lead to stack overflow'

Tags: java, regex, sonarlint

I have lines in a CSV file that look like the line below:

`"A","B","C"`

I can be certain that all values will always be in double-quotes, and separated by commas.

To parse out the values, I use this regex:

```
var regex  = ",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";
var chunks = Stream.of(s.split(regex))
               .map(e -> e.substring(1, e.length() - 1))
               .toList();
```

This results in a `chunks` list holding the values `A`, `B`, `C`. So far so good.
However, SonarLint is complaining about the regex. It says:

`Refactor this repetition that can lead to a stack overflow for large inputs`

What would the regex need to look like to avoid a stack overflow from happening?

Comment: Why don't you just split on `", "` (comma space)?

Comment: Ouch. Well spotted. That's an error in the question, I don't have a space after the comma. I'll edit my question now.

Comment: Apparently it did lead to stackoverflow, but I've edited the title to reflect the actual error :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to pick characters outside of pair of quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632475/regex-to-pick-characters-outside-of-pair-of-quotes)

Comment: Or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105360/regex-find-comma-not-inside-quotes

Comment: This regex is redundant here.. If you are certain that the values are always in double quotes and separated by a comma. Just directly pass it as a string and get the value. The error states that this regex will point your code to memory stack overflowing when handling larger string input

Comment: You should be using a CSV parser here rather than regex.

Comment: @Nick - None of the potential duplicates address my question specifically. 'Just directly pass it as a string and get the value' - what would that look like?

Comment: @ChRyder both offer another way of matching a `,` not inside quotes, which as far as I can see is what you are trying to do.

Comment: The regex, which matches a comma not within brackets using a standard approach, looks fine. Ignore the warning.

Answer (score -1):

This is because your regex is having repetitions. Consider rethinking optimization.
I believe, in your case `",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"` gives same result as `",(?=([^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"` which you may consider. 
You can refer to the complete sonar rule over [here](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/regex/RSPEC-5998/) which states:

> Why is this an issue? The Java regex engine uses recursive method
> calls to implement backtracking. Therefore when a repetition inside a
> regular expression contains multiple paths (i.e. the body of the
> repetition contains an alternation (|), an optional element or another
> repetition), trying to match the regular expression can cause a stack
> overflow on large inputs. This does not happen when using a possessive
> quantifier (such as *+ instead of *) or when using a character class
> inside a repetition (e.g. [ab]* instead of (a|b)*).

Comment: Your regex does not yield the same result as OP. You do not match the `"` before the C.