# Replace commas that are not within double inverted commas("") from csv files using powershell?

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, csv

I have a huge csv file(around 100GB). My problem is that I need to replace commas(,) in the file with semi-colon(;) except for the ones within double-inverted commas(""). 

I tried several methods but none seem to be working. Also this modification needs to be on Windows, hence sed and awk are out of option.

Example:

Input : "A,B,C",D,E,"FG","H,J",K

Output : "A,B,C";D;R;"FG";H,J;K

Once this is done, I need to remove the ".

I am able to remove the " from the file, but semi-colon replacement is failing everytime.

Please let me know if this is achievable through Powershell.

Comment: 100 GB csv? I ain't gonna believe it

Comment: Your example seems to be wrong. Please fix it.

Comment: Why are `sed` and `awk` out of the question? http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If sed and awk can be used, it would be wonderful. But the file is in a Windows box and not Linux.

Comment: You shouldn't do it this way. Use a programming language that has support for CSV files. Read in your file as a comma-separated file, then write it out as a ;-separated file without quotes (unless not necessary to protect a semicolon in the content).

Comment: By the way it's not hard to install sed, awk, or a real language like python on Windows.

Comment: gc file.csv -r 1000 |% {$_ -replace '","|",|,"',';' -replace '^"'} | sc  newfile.csv

Comment: Last comment should read: gc file.csv -r 1000 |% {$_ -replace '","|",|,"',';' -replace '^"'} | ac  newfile.csv  This is a different regex than the linked solution becuase it's not exactly the same problem - he doesn't want to keep the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should take care of both the delimiter replacement and removing the double quotes:

```
 Get-Content ./File.csv -ReadCount 1000 |
 foreach { $_ -replace ',(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)',';' -replace '"' } |
 Add-Content ./NewFile.csv
```

and handle a large file efficiently without needing third party utilities.

Comment: The code does not work in cases when fields are not wrapped within "".
For example: "A,B",C,D,"E"
It returns A,B;C,D;E"

Comment: I can take care of that trailing " easily enough (see updated answer).  If that's not what you want, then I'm misunderstanding what you mean by removing the ".  Exactly what should that final output look like?

Comment: My apologies.  The regex in the post origally flagged as a duplicate does work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632475/regex-to-pick-commas-outside-of-quotes (you should go upvote that), but the powershell implementation for what you're wanting to do is different than using it with the unix utilities.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly. Is there any way the performance could be improved? Altering the readcount value doesnt seem to make much of a difference.