# How remove break lines (/s) recursively from string with doubles quotes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I want to remove all break lines recursively from string with doubles quotes but I'm only removing one.

I'm doing this but I just remove one:

```
string.gsub(/\"(.*)\s(.*)\"/,'\1,\2')
```

Comment: Without any knowledge of Ruby, I'm guessing a `/g` flag would do it: `string.gsub(/\"(.*)\s(.*)\"/g,'\1,\2')` (Note that `\s` matches a whitespace character, not just a ‘break line[sic]’.)

Comment: @fcastillo post an example along with expected output.

Comment: `\s` is not a breakline, it will match every space and tab.

Comment: anyone mark this question as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632475/regex-to-pick-commas-outside-of-quotes , here is the regex https://regex101.com/r/fS8xR4/2

Comment: Well, I want to read a CSV file in Rails and in some fields exists a break line  and Rails detect that it's the end of file so I want to remove break lines that are between doubles quotes.

Comment: @Biffen: Ruby doesn't support the `/g` (global) modifier; that's what the `gsub()` method is for. That's as opposed to to `sub()`, which only does one substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
string = 'hello "there cruel world"'

string.gsub(/\"[^"]+?\"/) do |match|
  match.gsub(/\s+/, ', ')
end

#=> 'hello "there, cruel, world"'
```

Surely it is possible with a single regex, however this way is much more readable.

Comment: It doesn't work good because in string var still have the same value: `string.gsub(/\"[^"]+?\"/) do |match|
          eoo += match.gsub(/\s+/, ', ')
        end` In eoo = "there, cruel, world" but string = 'hello "there cruel world"'

Comment: Then change first `gsub`, to `gsub!`