# Powershell Parsing CSV file that contains comma

Tags: parsing, powershell, csv

Consider that CSV file:

```
Node Name,Client Name,Job Directory,Policy Name
server1,test.domain.com,"vmware:/?filter= VMHostName AnyOf "server2.domain.com", "server3.domain.com"",TEST
```

My code:

```
$events = Import-Csv "C:\file.csv" | foreach {
New-Object PSObject -prop @{
Server = $_.{Node Name};
Client = $_.{Client Name};
{JobDirectory/Script} = $_.{Job Directory};
Policy = $_.{Policy Name};  
}
}
```

I have some problems when I try to parse the third field. I am not sure if its because the comma, or the double quote.

This is the object I would like to have:

```
Node Name           : server1
Client Name         : test.domain.com
JobDirectory/Script : vmware:/?filter= VMHostName AnyOf "server2.domain.com", "server3.domain.com"
Policy Name         : TEST
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is that really how your csv is formed? Where every second line is actually a continuation of the previous? Also do you have any control over how this csv is created?

Comment: I've edited my original post. Now I think its more clear. I can't control the creation of the cvs file.

Comment: Yes it is because of the lack of closing double quote. Never seen this behaviour. If you manually add the closing quote it works. Could use `get-content` for this i think

Comment: You just changed your csv content. I was working on an answer based on what it was previously. Does it not have a new line now?

Comment: Sorry Matt, No new line. (i've corrected code format again). Thanks!

Comment: `If ($thirdfield | Select-String -Pattern '"",') {
 $thirdfield = $string -replace ",",";" }`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the easiest way to approach this is to read the file in with `Get-Content` and then split each line where the commas are not inside quotes. I borrowed the regex from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25544437/3829407) for this.

Using your current input data I would do something like this

```powershell
$filedata = Get-Content C:\temp\test.csv
$asObject = ForEach($singlerow in ($filedata | Select-Object -Skip 1)){
    $props = @{}
    $singlerow = $singlerow -split ',(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)'
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        Server = $singlerow[0]
        Client = $singlerow[1]
        "JobDirectory/Script" = $singlerow[2]
        Policy = $singlerow[3]
    }
}
```

**Sample Output** from `$asObject | Format-List`

```powershell
Server              : server1
Client              : test.domain.com
JobDirectory/Script : "vmware:/?filter= VMHostName AnyOf "server2.domain.com", "server3.domain.com""
Policy              : TEST
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Nice code. What about this pseudocode?. If I find a double quote and a  semicolon replace comma for semicolon.. `If ($thirdfield | Select-String -Pattern '"",') {  $thirdfield = $string -replace ",",";" }`

Comment: Not sure what context you are calling this. How is `$thirdfield` defined? Why would you replace that last comma with a semicolon. If you don't want to use my code and have another avenue then update this question or ask another one.

Comment: No, no... your code is perfect and works very well! I am jealous.. :) I was rambling. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Another way using your starting code

```
$obj = gc c:\temp\test.csv |
% { $_ -replace '"(\b[^"]*\b)"','$1' } |
    convertfrom-csv | % {  [pscustomobject][ordered] @{
    Server = $_.{Node Name}
    Client = $_.{Client Name}
    {JobDirectory/Script} = $_.{Job Directory}
    Policy = $_.{Policy Name} }
  }
```