# String split regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a `string` that represents a command. Each command can be a different length. For example here are some commands

- `showmessage "hello im the message"`
- `exit`
- `showmessage "im the message" "im the title"`
- `playsound /path/to/sound/file`

My function takes a `string` that has the whole command and currently splits the `string` into a `string` array using `split("\\s+")`.

However this splits the command at every whitespace. What I need to do is split the command at each space UNLESS something in the command started with `"` and ends with `"`. In this case I'd need to split the `string` so that the `string` array contains a `string` that is the whole part of the command that is in quotes.

So if the input command was:

`showmessage "the message"`

the split `string` array would contain the `strings`:

`showmessage`, `"the message"`

and if the command was:

`showmessage the message`

the split array would contain:

`showmessage`, `the`, `message`

Is there a way to do this with regexes?

Comment: Even if there is a way to do this with Regex, a parser would be the better thing to handle this. Did you consider that showing a message with quotation marks needs escaping of these like `showmessage "message with \"quotes\"" "title"`?

Comment: And here is [another answer you can use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632475/regex-to-pick-commas-outside-of-quotes).

Comment: There's an old class called [`StreamTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) that's suitable for parsing simple command languages. Take a look to see if it suits you.

Comment: @Thomas I didn't consider the escaping, thanks.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'll check that out, thanks