# c# Regex specific extraction

Tags: c#, regex, string

Not CSV

Sandboxed Enviroment.

I am trying to extract a few "values" from a string. The string will more or less be consistent. I have come to conclusion I will need to rely on regex for this. I can't quite figure out the regex piece.

```
string str1 = "test \"test1\" \"35\" TestWord Test";
string str2 = "test \"test2\" \"this is a Test\" TestWord2 Test2";
```

I want my result for each string to basically "split" at each space unless it is in quotes. I know this is not regex, but it is an example of what I want to accomplish.

```
string[] split = str1.split(' ');
```

This works fine, for there are no spaces in between the quotes

```
string[] split = str2.split(' ');
```

This won't work because there are spaces in between the second quoted portion.

This is why I think regex is the best bet, aside from parsing, the old fashioned way as it were.

I want every piece of extracted data from the string stored into an array.

So for the first example

```
string[] split = str1.split(' ');
```

my result should be

```
split[0] = test
split[1] = test1
split[2] = 35
split[3] = TestWord
split[4] = Test
```

and yes I would like to omit any quotes in the results.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: That linked answer has almost nothing to do with the OP question!

Comment: Something like this? It's just `\w+` http://regexr.com/3cjpu

Comment: @RicGaudet: There is everything OP needs. No need to use a regex here. Use a built-in CSV parser with a space as a separator. `"test \"test2\" \"this is a Test\" TestWord2 Test2"` gets split into `test`, `test2`, `this is a Test`, `TestWord2`, `Test2`.

Comment: @Angryjames: Your strings are parseable with CSV. Add `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;`, and this method: `public static string[] ParseCSVString(string csv, string separator)
        {
            TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(csv));

            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            parser.SetDelimiters(separator);
            string[] fields = null;

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
                fields = parser.ReadFields();
            parser.Close();
            return fields;
        }`

Comment: I guess I should mention I am limited because of the sandboxed nature of what i am writing for. I cannot use just any library.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: I understand that the CSV parser works, but that does not mean the question should be closed just because there is a third party library out there that can do the job.

Comment: @RicGaudet: It is not not a 3rd party, it is a native library that you can use in VS. The same questions have been asked and that solution was always marked as accepted. I am here a year, every day, at regex tag. I know what I am saying. I know regex. **Regex is not the right tool for this job**.

Comment: @Angryjames: Does the sandboxed environment forbids adding `using`s? Note that `string str2 = test "test2" "this is a Test" TestWord2 Test2` does not even compile. Anyway, the regex is already there for several years: [`@"\p{Zs}+(?=[^""]*(?:""[^""]*""[^""]*)*$)"`](https://regex101.com/r/xP7eH9/1). See [*Regex to pick commas outside of quotes*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632475/regex-to-pick-commas-outside-of-quotes).

Comment: The Sandbox is limited to certain "libraries / using" Native VB is not one of them as far as i know.