# How to split but ignore separators in quoted strings in R?

Tags: r, split, data.table

I am splitting strings separated by comma, but, I want to ignore commas between quotations. Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
dataset <- data.frame(str=c("USATW,\"USA Technologies, Inc Warrants\",Q" ,
                            "DUSA,DUSA Pharmaceuticals Inc,Q"))

#1   USATW,"USA Technologies, Inc Warrants",Q
#2   DUSA,DUSA Pharmaceuticals Inc,Q

setDT(dataset)[, c("Symbol","Security Name","Market Category") :=
                    tstrsplit(str, ",", fixed=TRUE)]


#   Symbol    Security Name               Market Category
#1  USATW    "USA Technologies            Inc Warrants"
#2  DUSA      DUSA Pharmaceuticals Inc    Q
```

The first string should be:

```
#1  USATW    "USA Technologies, Inc Warrants"  Q
```

There are similar posts but in other programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/632552/2994949) will split by comma and keep the quotes

```
library(data.table)
dataset <- data.frame(str=c("USATW,\"USA Technologies, Inc Warrants\",Q" ,
                            "DUSA,DUSA Pharmaceuticals Inc,Q"))

setDT(dataset)[, c("Symbol","Security Name","Market Category") :=
                 tstrsplit(str, '(,)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)', perl = TRUE)]

#                                         str Symbol                    Security Name Market Category
# 1: USATW,"USA Technologies, Inc Warrants",Q  USATW "USA Technologies, Inc Warrants"               Q
# 2:          DUSA,DUSA Pharmaceuticals Inc,Q   DUSA         DUSA Pharmaceuticals Inc               Q
```

Answer (score 6):

Try `read.table`.  No packages are needed.

```
read.table(text = as.character(dataset$str), sep = ",", as.is = TRUE,   
  col.names = c("Symbol", "Security Name", "Market Category"), check.names = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
  Symbol                  Security Name Market Category
1  USATW USA Technologies, Inc Warrants               Q
2   DUSA       DUSA Pharmaceuticals Inc               Q
```

Comment: right, but I think op wants to preserve the escaped quotes for some reason

Comment: you can also use `fread` if you sprinkle in line breaks: `fread(paste(dataset$str, collapse = '\n'), header = F)`