# Spliting a string between "," JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, split

This is my original string,

```
required:true,validType:'timegt['#timeofdaymeterslotonebegintime,#timeofdaymeterslotoneendtime']
```

I want to split into two. the output will be like

```
required:true 
 validType:'timegt['#timeofdaymeterslotonebegintime,#timeofdaymeterslotoneendtime']
```

Can someone help me out with this.

Comment: You write code, we (maybe) try help fix it. We're not here to write code for you.

Comment: Perhaps [`string.split(",", 2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) would do?

Comment: FYI, JavaScript's String type has a `split` method that works just like Java's. [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

Comment: Is your problem more general than your single example ? is it by any chance something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632475/regex-to-pick-commas-outside-of-quotes ?

Answer (score 1):

**first solution**  you split the string to obtain the two values in an Array :

```
var str = "required:true,validType:'timegt['#timeofdaymeterslotonebegintime,#timeofdaymeterslotoneendtime']";
var arr = str.split(",");
var result = [];
result.push(arr[0]);
result.push(arr.filter((element, index) => (index>0)).join());
console.log(result);
```

**second solution** you extract from the initial string two strings containing your values :

```
var str = "required:true,validType:'timegt['#timeofdaymeterslotonebegintime,#timeofdaymeterslotoneendtime']";
var index = str.indexOf(",");
var result1 = str.slice(0, index);
var result2 = str.slice(index+1);
console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: var str having two "," mate, your first solution doesn't work

Comment: Yes shame on me !   I've debugged just upstairs. And this time I've tested : that works !!!!