# Regex - get characters except between sample

Tags: regex

I have a string filled with data like these that I want to split based on comma :

```
16588, 16503, 1, 1, N'1, 2, 3 RUE MENESTRELS', 12, 153
```

In this exemple I want the output to be like these :

```
{16588|16503|1|1|N'1, 2, 3 RUE MENESTRELS'|12|153}
```

The fact is that if I do a split based upon a comma, I'll get this result :

```
{16588|16503|1|1|N'1|2|3 RUE MENESTRELS'|12|153}
```

I think a regex can solve this, but after searching for a while I haven't found a solution yet... (And I must confess that I'm not very good with regex too)

To summarize, I'd like to split a string based on all comma, except comma between the characters `N'` and the characters `'`

I tried to use this sample but it doesn't work

```
\,(?!N[^']*')
```

Sorry for mistakes, English is not my first language and thank you in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to pick commas outside of quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632475/regex-to-pick-commas-outside-of-quotes)

Comment: What language or tool are you using this regex pattern in?  You are saying `split` but you are displaying with pipes and wrapping in curly brackets.  Can you better explain what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
(,)(?=(?:[^']|'[^']*')*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vt2mUX/2)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after this:

```
(N'.*?')
```

See it here [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Vt2mUX/1)

Comment: The answer that Egan Wolf (see above) give what the solution I wanted, but thanks too !

Answer (score 0):

If your tool/language permits `(*SKIP)` AND `(*FAIL)`, my pattern will provide the same result with a quarter of the effort of Egan's.

```
/('[^']*'(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|,/    #just 105 steps
```

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/VZIjSl/1)

The first alternative matches substrings between single quotes then discards them.
This leaves the second alternative to correctly match the remaining/qualifying commas.