# Need RegEx for replacing all commas outside of double quotes and replaceing with | - in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have string like :

```
8/30/2021 19:22,server1,app1,"user1, Mrs. user2",US,One,Email, Sent,Success
```

Expected Output :

```
8/30/2021 19:22|server1|app1|user1, Mrs. user2|US|One|Email| Sent|Success
```

My code looks like :

```
....
line = line.replace(',', '|')
print (line)
```

How to handle double quotes in python using RegEx ?

Comment: If it's a csv file, I would recommend using a csv module to do it for you. E.g. `pandas.read_csv(file_name).to_csv(sep="|")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my answer is merely a hack, but delivers desired results:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = '8/30/2021 19:22,server1,app1,"user1, Mrs. user2",US,One,Email, Sent,Success'
print("|".join(pd.read_csv(StringIO(s)).columns))
```

Outputs:

```
'8/30/2021 19:22|server1|app1|user1, Mrs. user2|US|One|Email| Sent|Success'
```

I kind of would guess though that you could find an answer by googling? :)
Or check out the source code of the pandas library!

**Update** - yes, 5 min of Google Fu revealed the answer! here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/632552/551694
Please go and upvote.

```
re.sub('(,)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)','|',s)
```

delivers

```
'8/30/2021 19:22|server1|app1|"user1, Mrs. user2"|US|One|Email| Sent|Success'
```